# Why is CakePHPs cake_core_method_cache file getting bigger over time?

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu, cakephp-2.4

we're having quite a big CakePHP (currently 2.4.7) SAAS-app. It's pretty mature and until last week we never had any real problems concerning the functionality provided by CakePHPs-core.

Last weekend we ran into a very alarming situation, where our app got really slow and faulty. We looked into all kind of server monitorings and found out, that i/o stats had skyrocketed in the last couple of hours. After some more investigation we isolated the problem to Cake's '**cake_core_method_cache**' file. On an average day, this file has a size of 200 kb. Last weekend, it went up to ~ 40 mb.

Part of our deploy-routine is to remove all cache files from the app/tmp/cache and app/tmp/persistent folders. Because we deploy very often (few times a day), the cache gets cleared very often. Unfortunately, holidays last week paused our deployments and it looked like this was a problem for the core/caching-functionality.

So, my two questions are:

a) does anyone know, why the cake_core_method_cache is getting bigger over time?

b) is there any other possibility to solve this problem as to delete this file on a constant basis?

Comment: that doesn't sound like a normal scenario - you may find some information by looking that the file's contents. E.g., is it the same contents repeated many times? Compared to it's normal/small state - is it full of unrelated junk?

Comment: It looks like that there were db-instances of models stored directly in this file - of course serialized. i have no idea why and how this data got there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How is this cache used

The only references to method_cache in CakePHP are in [Dbo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L775) [Source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L3310). This is a cache that is used extensively throughout that class to cache the result of [(relatively) expensive quoting operations](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L809-L846), or as indicated by [a relevant docblock](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L53-L60):

> Caches result from query parsing operations. Cached results for both DboSource::name() and DboSource::conditions() will be stored here.

Consider the following shell:

```
<?php

class SoShell extends AppShell {

    function main() {
        $this->Post = ClassRegistry::init('Post');

        $this->Post->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'find-this-text' => 'x'
            )
        ));

        debug(DboSource::$methodCache);
    }

}
```

Running it, produces the following output:

```
> Console/cake so
########## DEBUG ##########
array(
    'name' => array(
        'f5442d1f57be5d9d8ac80ae9613d5ff9' => '`database_name`',
        'cfacfed443d6f30e67edf9bbcb06ce30' => '`posts`',
        'e13d78515036382daf55fa083088c902' => '`Post`.`id`',
        'aafd056e6d53878a75ab4ee3f18645a1' => '`Post`.`title`',
        '4084e974416e3a7fb06e6a280721637b' => '`Post`.`body`',
        'b4f1ad1de4cdc3a3f82e905f8dfd8673' => '`Post`.`created`',
        'bfeffce70e344d7606e17c9ff24530b5' => '`Post`.`modified`',
        'e42609d9744a7d1ce80c8d838b9ea07c' => '`find-this-text`', # <-
        'c0a33fa0f04ac4682dcdc4b25167b3a8' => '`Post`'
    ),
    'fields' => array(
        '952d56c2bf037c8195bdd5fba57b1024' => array(
            (int) 0 => '`Post`.`id`',
            (int) 1 => '`Post`.`title`',
            (int) 2 => '`Post`.`body`',
            (int) 3 => '`Post`.`created`',
            (int) 4 => '`Post`.`modified`'
        )
    )
)
```

Note that the cache contains "user" (or developer) input, that array is what is written to the cache [at the end of a request](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L3305-L3312).

This example should also highlight why the cache grows with time - the cache is dependent on the queries issued to date and as time goes by more query permutations are issued by an application leading to the method cache growing (but not usually to many MB).

### Easy fix

There's a very simple fix to the described problem: Disable the method cache.

i.e. put the following anywhere in your application:

```
DboSource::$cacheMethods = false;
```

This will of course mean a deterioration in performance as there will be no method caching used, so relatively expensive preg-based quoting operations will occur on every request.

### Better fix

If the cache is being filled with "db-instances of models" - it's quite possible there is an application problem somewhere. It's not normal, it shouldn't happen and is dependent on exactly what the application is doing. Given that it's not possible to give a specific solution.

However, if you can identify *any* specific key in the cache containing a large chunk of data, you can use it to find what query is responsible. For example:

```
// anywhere
if (isset(DboSource::$methodCache['name']['e42609d9744a7d1ce80c8d838b9ea07c']) {
    // a query with find-this-text has been issued somewhere
}
```

You can (temporarily) add this kind of logic to [where the dbo methodCache property is modified](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L781) to be able to detect modifications "in situ":

```
public function cacheMethod($method, $key, $value = null) {
    if ($this->cacheMethods === false) {
        return $value;
    }
    if (!$this->_methodCacheChange && empty(self::$methodCache)) {
        self::$methodCache = Cache::read('method_cache', '_cake_core_');
    }
    if ($value === null) {
        return (isset(self::$methodCache[$method][$key])) ? self::$methodCache[$method][$key] : null;
    }
    $this->_methodCacheChange = true;
    
    // Added
    if ($method === 'name' && $key === 'e42609d9744a7d1ce80c8d838b9ea07c') {
        App::uses('Debugger', 'Utility');
        $this->log("Query with find-this-text in it issued", "wat-debug");      
        $this->log(Debugger::trace(), "wat-debug");     
    }
    // Added end

    return self::$methodCache[$method][$key] = $value;
}
```

This would permit you to identify what is directly responsible for injecting large volumes of data into the method cache; to then correct the application code so that the method cache can be enabled and used as designed.

Comment: Thx for your help, you made my week! After reading your answer, I checked our app and found a "problem" in one of our SQL-queries. Instead of having a 'Model.created BETWEEN ? AND ?', we had a 'Model.created BETWEEN '$DATE' AND '$DATE'. It looks like, that with the second syntax, every $DATE-value we put into the query is cached in the cake_core_method_cache_file.

Comment: > DboSource::$cacheMethods = false;

Doing this gices: `Access to undeclared static property: DboSource::$cacheMethods`

It's not declared static in CakePHP 2.x => what's the proper procedure here?

Comment: Obtain a reference to that instance - and [change the value](https://github.com/tersmitten/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L54-L70) mark

Comment: But how can I obtain it without forcing a connection being created? Because it's not static, you can't set it global and in common places like boostrap/config the connections aren't established yet. The application might have multiple entry points (console, controller) and I'm not sure where to really put it. Also multiple database connection don't make that easier, seems I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't have any 2.x cake projects to poke around with - please update the answer when you figure it out, given php's behavior has changed :)

Comment: I added my solution as answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54323489/47573

Answer (score 1):

With the most recent old CakePHP 2 version the proposed fix from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23287510/47573 didn't work for me anymore; the property is not static and thus you can't simply override somewhere else.

The solution I came up with was to create a customized Database driver extending the one from CakePHP I use:

- create `app/Plugin/PostgresCustom/Model/Datasource/Database/PostgresCustom.php`
- this class extends Cakes `Postgres` which in turns extends `DboSource` which defines this property
- in my `PostgresCustom` class I simply override the property via `public $cacheMethods = false;`
- in `app/Config/bootstrap.php` I register the plugin via `CakePlugin::load('PostgresCustom');`
- in `app/Config/database.php` I changed the value for `datasource` everywhere to `PostgresCustom.Database/PostgresCustom`
- Profit